# Go MinGW compiler complains about if-else statement

Tags: go

Consider the following (useless) [Go](http://golang.org) function:

```
func domagic(n int) int {
    if n > 10 {
        return n;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This gives me the following compiler error:

> main.go:15: function ends without a return statement

However, if i return a value outside the if-else block (before the end of the function), it compiles without errors.

Is this behavior by design, or is it something simply not yet implemented in the [Go MinGW](http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/list)  compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple googling for the exact compiler error message yields [this bugtracker issue](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=65). So I'd not say it's "by design" as it looks more like "it'd just happened to be implemented this way".  See also [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.go.general/34710/focus=34711).

Answer (score 1):

It's by design. Write:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func domagic(n int) int {
    if n > 10 {
        return n
    }
    return 0
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(domagic(7), domagic(42))
}
```

Output:

```
0 42
```